# Make Git Extensions show pending changes in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git

I've just switched from SVN to Git. I installed `Git Extensions` in hope of achieving similar functionality to `AnkhSVN` that I previously used with `Visual Studio 2010`. Unfortunately, although Git menu appeared in Visual Studio and context menus work in `Solution Explorer` (I am able to view changes history), the `Pending Changes` window is always empty. Also there are no notification icons in Solution Explorer that shows git status of the files.

Does these features are supported by Git Extensions at all or do I need some other plugin like `Visual Studio Tools for Git` or `Git Source Control Provider`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@SiliconMind, I had the same question and found out installing [Git Source Control Provider](https://gitscc.codeplex.com/) gave me that Pending Changes window I was used to seeing when having an SVN source control binding.

After installing, remember to set the *Source control plug-in* to **Git Source Control Provider** (Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Plug-in Selection).

[image]